# Tablet space for apps from its own internal USB storage

Tags: stock-android, tablet, adoptable-storage

I have a Tecno tablet with:
 1 gb RAM/engine
 1 gb Internal Storage/apps installing only. 
 16 gb "USB Storage" internally built (just named like that but it's not external),media/ files

I do NOT have, NOR want to use an SD/microSD/memory card.

How can I merge or add up from that USB Storage
 Increase apps installed (the Internal Storage gets full fast;it is the Default Write Disk) 
& any other tweaks to do, PC software, apps, wielding???

I have:- WiFi, this rooted tablet, rooted Android phone, USB cables, Windows laptop, NO SD card.

HOW please?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I do not think that you can install more RAM on most Android devices as they have fixed amounts of RAM. I would suggest that you minimize background processes in order to free up more RAM.

Secondly, I also do not think that you can install more Internal Storage to an Android device, again because the amount is fixed. The only way is to add an SD Card/MicroSD Card which you do not want.

If you install apps to USB Storage, don't you have to constantly keep it plugged in in order for them to run?

Comment: No that other storage is internal just named "USB Storage" but can only hold media/files. It is not external/actual USB drive/flash. No. So16gb storage + 1gb for apps installing. Thank you though.